# How to change the color of outliers in boxplot with boxplot()?

Tags: r, boxplot

I am trying to color the outliers in my boxplot in black. I managed to color the box in grey but I cant figure out how to color outliers. (the white points on the graph)

```
boxplot(y1$Frequency..times., col="grey")
```

Thanks in advance for the help
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
boxplot(y1$Frequency..times., col="grey", outcol="red")
```

or preferably, but longer

```
boxplot(y1$Frequency..times., col="grey", pars=list(outcol="red"))
```

It's all in the manual, but it can be hard to find if you aren't that experienced. When reading `?boxplot`, notice the description of the `pars` argument.

> pars
>
> > a list of (potentially many) more **graphical parameters**, e.g., *boxwex* or *outpch*; these are passed to **bxp** (if plot is true); for details, see there.

`?bxp` in turn it tells you that there is a number of arguments that control the appearance of outliers.

> pars, ...
>
> > outlty, outlwd, outpch, outcex, outcol, outbg:
> >
> > > outlier line type, line width, point character, point size expansion, color, and background color. The default outlty = "blank" suppresses the lines and outpch = NA suppresses points.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. but do you know how to color the inside of the outliers? outcol on colors the outline. Thanks!

Comment: May I add that `outcol` is not found in `?boxplot`, but if you look in the 'See Also' section it is referred to `bxp`. This is quite often the case in R: if you don't find what you are looking for in the help text for the current function, just keep on digging in 'See also'.

Comment: To color the inside you must select a filled [plot character](http://rgraphics.limnology.wisc.edu/images/miscellaneous/pch.png), that is any between 21-25. Then you can use `boxplot(y, outpch=25, outcol="green", outbg="yellow")`.